# How do I compare these two Arrays for sameness?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array consisting of seat number in the following format

```
<?php
 $seatnumbers = array(
    "A1" => "1","A2" => "2",
    "B1" => "3","B2" => "4","B3" => "5",
    "C1" => "6","C2" => "7","C3" => "8",
    "D1" => "9","D2" => "10","D3" => "11",
    "E1" => "12","E2" => "13","E3" => "14"
    );
?>
```

And also the retrieved data of reserved seats by users which comes in this format

```
<?php
  $seat = array();
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT booked_seat FROM mybooking where bus_id = '{$l}'"); 
  $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   foreach($row as $r){
     $seat[] = $r['booked_seat'];  
  }
  print_r($seat)
  // Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => D2 )
?>
```

All I am trying to achieve is to disable the selected seats in a `HTML select` like I tried doing here

```
<?php
    $keys = array_keys($seatnumbers);
    $values = array_values($seatnumbers);

    $skeys = array_keys($seat);
    $val = array_values($seat);

    for($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++ )
     {

       if($keys[$i] == $val[$i]){
         echo "<option disabled>". $keys[$i]. "(Booked)</option>"; 

       }else{
         echo "<option value='".$keys[$i]."'>". $keys[$i]."-". $val[$i]. "(Available)</option>";
       }
     }                     
    ?>
```

But only the first option showed **booked**. How do compare for two arrays to disabled the reserved seats. 
Here is the result of what I tried [image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using prepared statements and also using `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` to save having to process the result set from the SQL further.  The code has comments to show how this is done.

You will have to change the output, but it matches what you have enough to modify it...

```
$query = "SELECT booked_seat FROM mybooking where bus_id = :busID";

$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute(["busID" => $l]);
// Fetch an array with just the values of booked_seat
$seat=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
// Flip array so the seat name becomes the key
$seat = array_flip($seat);
$seatnumbers = array(
    "A1" => "1","A2" => "2",
    "B1" => "3","B2" => "4","B3" => "5",
    "C1" => "6","C2" => "7","C3" => "8",
    "D1" => "9","D2" => "10","D3" => "11",
    "E1" => "12","E2" => "13","E3" => "14"
);

foreach ( $seatnumbers as $seatName => $number ) {
    echo $seatName;
    // If the key is set in the seat array, then it is booked
    if ( isset($seat[$seatName]) ){
        echo " Seat booked".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else    {
        echo " Seat not booked".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Worked as required.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical task for using foreach

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
    $seatnumbers = array(
    "A1" => "1","A2" => "2",
    "B1" => "3","B2" => "4","B3" => "5",
    "C1" => "6","C2" => "7","C3" => "8",
    "D1" => "9","D2" => "10","D3" => "11",
    "E1" => "12","E2" => "13","E3" => "14"
    );

    $seat = array(
    "0" => "A1","1" => "D2",
    "2" => "E1","3" => "E2","4" => "E3"
    );

    echo "<select>";
    foreach ($seatnumbers as $ikey=>$ivalue)
    {
       if(in_array($ikey,$seat)){
         echo "<option disabled>". $ikey. "(Booked)</option>";
       }else{
         echo "<option value='".$keys[$i]."'>". $ikey."-". $val[$i]. "(Available)</option>";
       }
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```